# What can be a proper way to handle sdl mouse events?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl

this questions seems to be quite common here on SO and I think I start getting a grasp on what to do, but the question is all split up so it is hard to get the full answer. The most answers seems to be of ad hoc style and implementing one suggestion may cause trouble some other way. I hope this question is narrow enough for this forum.

What I want to do is to find a way of handling mouse events properly. I use `SDL2` and `c++`. I would like to distinguish a few separate behaviours: mouse click, double click, mouse press and mouse movement. This is really where the problem occurs. I have written som code that moves a polygon the way I want (for each case except double click), but Before I proceed I need to have a way to notice what kind of event I have. The code written so far is this.

```
while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
{
    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ){ quit = true; }
    else if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
    keep_moving = true;
    printf("Button is pressed\n");
    }
    else if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP){
        keep_moving = false;
    printf("Button was released\n");
    }
}

if (keep_moving) { SDL_GetMouseState( &MOUSE_X, &MOUSE_Y ); }
```

This will only push an event when the mouse button is pressed or released. The current mouse state is also continously updated apart from the button press an release, which I think is the best way to go. This since mouse position does not necessary need to lead to an action (except moving the Icon which is handled by `windows`).

My first guess is that the decision of an event must depend on the time between the ocurring events in the above code. Like defining two variables `delta_down` and `delta_up` which can be used to decide if the mouse is pressed or clicked (`delta_down`) and if there is a double click (`delta_up`).

Movement may have been solved by the independent mouse state update, but I am not completely sure this is ok.

I also have seen some suggestion to identify click or move from some distance `delta_d`, but that seems it could be some problems when it comes to decide if the mouse is pressed or clicked.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: So are you asking how to check for double clicks, or do you want us to rewrite your entire even sequence?

Comment: I guess writing code is not covered in this forum, so if the question is to wide to give a proper answer or if the code is to bad to be able to adjust and make it work, then maybe a link or direction how the principles work would be fine. The question is rather finding a way to classify the different types of mouse events

Comment: Well I guess you could create your own enum. Something like this : `enum{ MouseUp, MouseDown, MouseDBLClick };`

Comment: So then the these delta times would be an "acceptable" way you think? I do not think that I would run into so much trouble for some rather simple applications at least.

Comment: Just clearly define "click" and "double click". Like "press and release within N milliseconds, with mouse being moved at most at M pixels". After that it is very likely you'll know how to implement it.

Comment: @keltar Thank you. This seems to be a good way of doing it. And I will take the "most M pixels" suggestion into account as well. When thinking about it may be good to have a distance condition as well.

Comment: well it's not that trivial, you have to "delay" the click event as you don't know whether it's going to be a double click.

Comment: Ok I see. That may be necessary. Will this cause trouble for Reading the keyboard later?

Comment: I tried to solve it by creating 2 variables to check time. if a "click" was registered I and the time to next mouse button up was short enough I regsterered a double click. It seems to work but I do not know if it is a bad solution?